# Updated state values are not displaying in react

Tags: reactjs

I am implementing a shopping cart in MERN. Once user increment or decrement the quantity of a product, the total price should update accordingly. (The increment and decrement buttons are in a child component). Once I click on increment or decrement button, it is updating the mongoDB successfully. From the both `increment` and `decrement` functions, updated Cart will get as the response and it will set to the state's Cart variable. Then `updateStates` method will trigger and updates the state variables (total & discount) according to the new Cart values. `total` & `discount` states are used to display the bill within this component (I have put some comments to find out). But the problem is, when I increment or decrement, it will not display updated bill value until I refresh the page. I want to update the values without refreshing the page manually. How can I fix this issue? Thanks in advance!

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, Component} from 'react';

import Titles  from "../Titles";
import CartColumns from './CartColumns';
import EmptyCart  from "./EmptyCart";

import CartList from "./CartList";
import CartTotals from "./CartTotals"
import NavBar from "../NavBar";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {Link, Redirect} from "react-router-dom";
import Axios from "axios";

const mapStateToProps = ({ session}) => ({
    session
});

class Cart extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.increment = this.increment.bind(this);
        this.decrement = this.decrement.bind(this);
        this.removeItem = this.removeItem.bind(this);
    }

    state = {
        Cart: [],
        total : 0,
        discount: 0
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        if(this.props.session.userId !== null){
            this.getItems();
        }
    }

    //get cart items of the user and set to the Cart variable in state
    getItems = () => {
        Axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/cart/getCart', {params:{userId: this.props.session.userId}})
            .then(res => {
                const cart = res.data;

                let tempProducts = [];
                cart.forEach(item => {
                    const singleItem = {...item};
                    tempProducts = [...tempProducts, singleItem];
                });

                this.setState({
                    Cart : tempProducts
                });

                this.updateStates();
            })
    };

    //this will update state values once increment or decrement happens
    updateStates = () => {
        this.setState({
            total : 0,
            discount : 0
        });

        this.state.Cart.forEach(item => {
            this.setState({
                total : this.state.total + (item.price * item.quantity),
                discount : this.state.discount + (item.discount * item.quantity)
            })
        })

    };

    //Increment the quantity of the product. 
    increment = (productId) => {
        const item = {
            userId : this.props.session.userId,
            productId: productId
        };

        Axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/cart/increment', item)
            .then(res=>{
                if(res.status === 200){
                    console.log('Incremented');

                    const cart = res.data;

                    let tempProducts = [];
                    cart.forEach(item => {
                        const singleItem = {...item};
                        tempProducts = [...tempProducts, singleItem];
                    });

                    this.setState({
                        Cart : tempProducts
                    });

                    this.updateStates();
                }
            });
    };

    //decrement the quantity of the product
    decrement = (productId) => {

        const product = this.state.Cart.find(item => item.id === productId );

        if(Number(product.quantity) > 1){

            const item = {
                userId : this.props.session.userId,
                productId: productId
            };

            Axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/cart/decrement', item)
                .then(res=>{
                    if(res.status === 200){
                        console.log('Decremented');

                        const cart = res.data;

                        let tempProducts = [];
                        cart.forEach(item => {
                            const singleItem = {...item};
                            tempProducts = [...tempProducts, singleItem];
                        });

                        this.setState({
                            Cart : tempProducts
                        })

                        //this.updateStates();
                    }
                });
        }

    };

    removeItem = (productId) => {
        //removes an item
    };

    render() {

        if(this.props.session.username !== null){
            return (
                <section>
                    <NavBar />
                    {(this.state.Cart.length > 0) ? (
                                    <React.Fragment>
                                        <Titles name ="Your " title = "Cart">Cart</Titles>
                                        <CartColumns/>
                                        <CartList cart = {this.state.Cart} increment={this.increment} decrement={this.decrement} removeItem={this.removeItem}/>
                                        {/*<CartTotals cart={this.state.Cart}/>*/}
                                        <div className="container">
                                            <div className="row">
                                                <div className="col-10 mt-2 ml-sm-5 ml-md-auto col-sm-8 text-capitalize text-right">
                                                    <h5>
                                                        <span className="text-title">Sub Total: </span>
                                                        //display the total from state
                                                        <strong>$ {this.state.total}</strong>
                                                    </h5>
                                                    <h5>
                                                        <span className="text-title">Discount: </span>
                                                        //display the discount from the state
                                                        <strong>$ {this.state.discount}</strong>
                                                    </h5>
                                                    <h5>
                                                        <span className="text-title">Total: </span>
                                                  //display the sub total by calculating the values
                                                        <strong>$ {this.state.total - this.state.discount}</strong>
                                                    </h5>

                                                    <Link to='/'>
                                                        <div className="col-10 mt-2 ml-sm-5 ml-md-auto col-sm-8 text-capitalize text-right">
                                                            <button className="btn btn-outline-danger text-uppercase mb-3 px-5" type="button"
                                                                    o>Clear Cart</button>
                                                            <button className="btn btn-outline-info ml-3 text-uppercase mb-3 px-5" type="button"
                                                            >Check Out</button>
                                                        </div>

                                                    </Link>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </React.Fragment>
                            ) : (
                                    <EmptyCart/>
                            )
                        }
                </section>
            );
        } else {
            return(
                <Redirect to="/login" />
            );
        }

    }
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps
)(Cart);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've missed how state updates in react are queued and reconciled. React state updates are asynchronous and batched processed between render/commit phases.

**Issues**

1. Your major error is queuing up a state update of `this.state.Cart` then immediately queuing updates *within the same cycle* to aggregate on the *new* cart. When you do this in `updateState` `this.state.Cart` is still the cart value from the current render cycle the update was queued in.
2. A second, nearly as major, error *also* occurs in `updateStates` when you `forEach` over the cart and queue up state updates using `this.state.total|discount` with the same reason. `this.state.total|discount` will be the same value each time so only the last state set will "stick".
3. The third "strike" and reason you need to reload the page is because you only compute the cart on `componentDidMount` and because of the above your code never actually updates the cart contents and thus re-renders the same content.

**Solution** - Use `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle function and more optimal state updates

Good news is, updating the cart isn't an issue in `getItems`, `increment`, or `decrement`, this works fine

```
this.setState({
  Cart: tempProducts
});
```

But this should be the end of the function. Time to let react lifecycle work for you!

Implement `componentDidUpdate`. This essentially will replace your `updateState` function.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  // Check if Cart updated
  if (prevState.Cart !== this.state.Cart) {
    // It did! Now compute new total and discount state
  }
}
```

Implement more optimal state update. In your code, queuing up multiple updates *is ok*, but you need to use a functional state update since each update ***depends*** on the previous state.

```
this.setState({ total: 0, discount: 0 });
this.Cart.forEach(({ discount, price, quantity }) => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    total: prevState.total + (price * quantity),
    discount: prevState.discount + (discount * quantity),
  }));
});
```

So the updated code now is

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  // Check if Cart updated
  if (prevState.Cart !== this.state.Cart) {
    // It did! Now compute new total and discount state
    this.setState({ total: 0, discount: 0 });
    this.Cart.forEach(({ discount, price, quantity }) => {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        total: prevState.total + (price * quantity),
        discount: prevState.discount + (discount * quantity),
      }));
    });
  }
}
```

This queues up many updates though, and all you really want to do is replace the total and discount values. You can aggregate those before and set state once with the new values by iterating over the cart and reducing the total and discount into a single (object) value. You no longer need to worry about previous state.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  // Check if Cart updated
  if (prevState.Cart !== this.state.Cart) {
    // It did! Now compute new total and discount state
    const totalAndDiscount = this.Cart.reduce(
      ({ total, discount }, item) => ({
        total: total + item.price * item.quantity,
        discount: discount + item.discount * item.quantity
      }),
      { total: 0, discount: 0 }
    );

    this.setState(totalAndDiscount);
  }
}
```

Comment: I learned lot of things from here. Although this solution did not solve my issue. Yet I am accepting your answer because you told that ```setState``` is subjected to being queued. So in my ```increment``` and ```decrement``` methods I am already setting the states if the response is succeeded. So I figure it out that's why total and discount values are not updating as the ```setState``` method used to update those is being queued. So what I did was in both ```increment``` and ```decrement``` methods, before posting the request, I filter out the price and discount to two variables

Comment: Then, after posting if the response is success(or 200) I updated the states ```total``` and the ```discount``` along with the ```Cart```. (if it is increment, add item price and discount to the current state value and vice versa in decrement). 
Thank you for this answer. You taught me the principles and that's gave me the idea to come up with a own way to solve this. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @MarketMAD Great! Yeah, without a running app we've only what was shared to debug by, those were just the more obvious issues I could see. Glad you got it sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

You are running into something that is called a stale closure. To update state efficiently you should not update state inside a loop rather try doing the following

```js
//this will update state values once increment or decrement happens
    updateStates = () => {
        let total = 0;
        let discount = 0;

        this.state.Cart.forEach(item => {
            total = total + (item.price * item.quantity);
            discount = discount + (item.discount * item.quantity);
        })

        this.setState({
            total : total,
            discount : discount
        });

    };
```