# How can I fix this problem in React Native Firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I have the next problem:

```
export async function updateLessons() { 
  let data
  await database().goOnline().then(async () => {
    await database()
    .ref('days')
    .on('value', snapshot => {
      console.log(snapshot.val())
      data = snapshot.val();
    });
  });

  return data;
}
```

I use this function to update my application when I swipe down

```
  const onRefresh = React.useCallback(async () => {
    setRefreshing(true);
    setLessons(await updateLessons());
    console.log(lessons)
    setRefreshing(false);
  }, []);
```

It is called from scroll view (refreshcontrol)
The problem is that it doesn't work asynchronously. In console log i see my snapshot. But the application updated faster and in console.log(lessons) it is undefined. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Updating state is an asynchronous operation, and won't have completed yet by the time your `console.log` statement runs.

A simple way to get the correct output, is to capture the new lessons in local variable (which *is* updated synchronously):

```
const onRefresh = React.useCallback(async () => {
  setRefreshing(true);
  const newLessons = await updateLessons();
  setLessons(newLessons);
  console.log(newLessons)
  setRefreshing(false);
}, []);
```

Also see:

- [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately), which also shows how to use a `useEffect` hook to respond to state changes.
- [React setState not updating state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41446560/react-setstate-not-updating-state)
- [Updated state values are not displaying in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61766010/updated-state-values-are-not-displaying-in-react)